# Using map and sum to apply a function and total the outcome

Tags: haskell

I'm out of my element a bit. I've been using higher order functions and I'm trying to apply a function AND use (.) to combine functions. I'm trying to write a function total that applies the function (first argument) to every element in the list (second argument) and sums the result.

I was given a specific type definition (which I'm not supposed to change) and I'm trying to `map` the function `f` to a list and then `sum` the returned list.

```
 total :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> Int
 total f x = sum x . map f x
```

I should get an Int that's the `sum` of the total. I get an error but it's one I'm unfamiliar with:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Int] -> c0'
* Probable cause: `(.)' is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression: sum x . map f
  In an equation for `total': total f x = sum x . map f
```

I need direction. I don't understand why `.` should be applied to more arguments.

Comment: You are trying to use `.` to compose `map f x`, but that is a list, not a function, so it does not compose with `.`. The error "applied to too few arguments" is due to `.` returning a function (`f . g` is the function obtained by composing function `f` and function `g`), but the type of `total` claims to return an `Int`. So, GHC wonders if the function resulting from `.` should be applied to some argument which you forgot. This is not the issue in your code, but this is why GHC generated that message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is fully applied so you shouldn't be using composition here.

Either use the application operator

```
total f x = sum x $ map f x
```

Or, if `sum` didn't require `x`, you could omit the explicit parameter to the function and use composition instead

```
total f = sum . map f
```

The composition operator is expecting a function, but you're fully applying `map` and passing the operator the list that `map` returned.

(I'm unfamiliar with a sum function that would accept an int though along with a list. Is that an error as well?)